# How do I change the heading separately?

Tags: javascript, html

I learn JavaScript and I am trying to change the `<em>"h1<em/>` element without affecting the `<em>break<em/>` element.

A button gives the "option" to change the city, which will present three prompts asking for first name, city, and temperature, resulting in `<em>"Hi ${firstName}! It is currently ${temperature}° in ${location}"<em/>`.

I want to change the emoji based on the temperature. When it's below 60°, the freezing emoji shows on top of the text, which would change .

My functions change the heading of the innerHTML. I have also attempted to assign separate classes, but my placements are where I am lost. I know how to change the heading as a whole but that wouldn't separate the Emoji and the text.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <style>
      h1,
      h2,
      h3 {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      h1 {
        color: #1a64d6;
        font-size: 34px;
        line-height: 48px;
        margin: 0;
      }

      h2 {
        margin: 0;

        font-size: 34px;
        line-height: 48px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }

      ul {
        padding: 0;
      }

      li {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      li:hover {
        background: #fffbef;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 18px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
      }

      button {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border: 1px solid #1a64d6;
        background: #1a64d6;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 22px;
        padding: 16px 24px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        transition: all 200ms ease;
        box-shadow: rgba(37, 39, 89, 0.08) 0px 8px 8px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      button:hover {
        background: white;
        color: #1a64d6;
        border: 1px solid #1a64d6;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <span class="emoji"></span>
      <br />
      <span class="currentCityTemp">Currently 21° in Tokyo</span>
    </h1>
    <h2>13° / <strong>23°</strong></h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h3>Tomorrow</h3>
        <p>10° / <strong>22°</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3> Saturday</h3>
        <p>15° / <strong>17°</strong></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>☀️ Sunday</h3>
        <p>25° / <strong>28°</strong></p>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button>Change city</button>
    <p>Coded by Matt Delac</p>
    <script>
      function heading(newHeading) {
        let h1A = document.querySelector(".emoji");
        h1A.innerHTML = changeCity;
        let h1B = document.querySelector(".currentCityTemp");
        h1B.innerHTML = changeCity;
      }
      function changeCity() {
        let firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
        let location = prompt("What city do you live in?");
        let temperature = prompt("What is the current temperature?");
        return temperature >= 60;
      }
      function headingChange() {
        if (heading) {
          h1A("");
          h1B(
            "Hi ${firstName}! It is currently ${temperature}° in ${location}"
          );
        } else {
          h1A("");
          h1B(
            "Hi ${firstName}! It is currently ${temperature}° in ${location}"
          );
        }
      }
      let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
      changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", changeCity);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but my placements are where I am lost"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Weather App</title>
        <style>
          h1,
          h2,
          h3 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          }

          h1 {
            color: #1a64d6;
            font-size: 34px;
            line-height: 48px;
            margin: 0;
          }

          h2 {
            margin: 0;

            font-size: 34px;
            line-height: 48px;
            font-weight: 400;
          }

          ul {
            padding: 0;
          }

          li {
            list-style: none;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 0;
            border-radius: 10px;
            transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }

          li:hover {
            background: #fffbef;
          }

          p {
            font-size: 18px;
            opacity: 0.7;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: monospace;
          }

          button {
            display: block;
            margin: 20px auto;
            border: 1px solid #1a64d6;
            background: #1a64d6;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 22px;
            padding: 16px 24px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            transition: all 200ms ease;
            box-shadow: rgba(37, 39, 89, 0.08) 0px 8px 8px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
          }

          button:hover {
            background: white;
            color: #1a64d6;
            border: 1px solid #1a64d6;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <span class="emoji"></span>
          <br />
          <span class="currentCityTemp">Currently 21° in Tokyo</span>
        </h1>
        <h2>13° / <strong>23°</strong></h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h3>Tomorrow</h3>
            <p>10° / <strong>22°</strong></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3> Saturday</h3>
            <p>15° / <strong>17°</strong></p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>☀️ Sunday</h3>
            <p>25° / <strong>28°</strong></p>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <button>Change city</button>
        <p>Coded by Matt Delac</p>
        <script>
          function heading(h1aText, h1bText) {
            let h1A = document.querySelector(".emoji");
            h1A.innerHTML = h1aText;
            let h1B = document.querySelector(".currentCityTemp");
            h1B.innerHTML = h1bText;
          }
          function changeCity() {
            let firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
            let location = prompt("What city do you live in?");
            let temperature = prompt("What is the current temperature?");
            headingChange(firstName, temperature, location);
          }
          function headingChange(firstName, temperature, location) {
            if (temperature > 60) {
              heading("", `Hi ${firstName}! It is currently ${temperature}° in ${location}`);
            } else {
              heading("", `Hi ${firstName}! It is currently ${temperature}° in ${location}`);
            }
          }
          let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
          changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", changeCity);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

That's how I would rewrite it.

1. As it was already mentioned, you should somehow send the variables from one function to another. That's what I did here `headingChange(firstName, temperature, location);`. We collected the values into variables, now we need the next function to use them.
2. Function `headingChange` selects the right emoji and text and sends it to the next function, `heading` which puts the in the right place.
3. If you want to use the `${variable}` construction, you need to use "`" symbol to define the string, because else interpolation will not work.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep this in mind for future use.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the following variables

```
let firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
let location = prompt("What city do you live in?");
let temperature = prompt("What is the current temperature?");
```

Aren't accessible outside of the function in which you define them. You are only returning a boolean from that function. The result of...

```
return temperature >= 60;
```

And, you're never calling the `headingChange()` function. If you did, you would see an error as it doesn't have access to those variables.

The same issue exists with the `h1A` and the `h1B` variables.
So, I would start by addressing those issues.

[Help understanding scope in Javascript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/scope-and-closures-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you. @Ryan O'D.  I decided to keep everything under one function. 

I initially didn't want it to be lengthy but I decided to add "<div>" and "<span>" to replace the "h1" variables.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, my initial goal was to utilize the `Single Responsibility Principle`, but I still have a ways to go.

I combined everything under `function changeCity()` as well as modified the `h1` with `div` and `span` elements and updated the variables.

```html
<h1>
      <div></div>
      <span>Currently 21° in Tokyo</span>
    </h1>
```

The updated result:

```js
<script>
      function changeCity() {
        let div = document.querySelector("div");
        div.innerHTML = prompt;
        let span = document.querySelector("span");
        span.innerHTML = prompt;
        let firstName = prompt("What is your first name?");
        let location = prompt("What city do you live in?");
        let temperature = prompt("What is the current temperature?");
        if (temperature >= 60) {
          div.innerHTML = "";
          span.innerHTML =
            "Hi " +
            firstName +
            "! It is currently " +
            temperature +
            "° in " +
            location;
        } else {
          div.innerHTML = "";
          span.innerHTML =
            "Hi " +
            firstName +
            "! It is currently " +
            temperature +
            "° in " +
            location;
        }
      }
      let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
      changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", changeCity);
    </script>
```

My assignment result:
[Updated header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwxw6.png)